# Regression on residuals within joint model

Tags: regression, bayesian, multilevel-analysis, residuals

I have a regression model (part of a larger hierarchical model) where I wish to try construct a regression using the residuals of a regression.

To simplify, say we have $j$ in $n$ observations, a $j \times r$ design matrix $X$, and corresponding coefficient vector $\beta$, such that
\begin{equation*}
    y = X\beta + \epsilon \\
    \epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)
\end{equation*}

Assuming we have equivalent observations and coefficients for each $k$ of $m$ subjects, we can write
\begin{equation}
    y_k = X_k\beta_k + \epsilon_k
\end{equation}
The residuals, $\epsilon_k$ are of interest to me. I would thus like to try to model differences in the residuals between subjects, using a vector of $p$ subject-specific covariates, $z_k$. This is where things get confusing for me. Now we would have
\begin{equation}
    \epsilon_k = z_k\psi_k \sim N(0,\sigma^2_k)
\end{equation}
I cannot place a prior on $z_k\psi_k$ though, since $z_k$ can vary arbitrarily. I then thought that perhaps the solution is to have a nested regression for the residuals, such that
\begin{equation}
    \epsilon_k \sim N(z_k\psi_k,\sigma^2_k) \ \text{or} \\
    \epsilon_k = z_k\psi_k + \tau_k, \ \ \tau_k\sim N(0, \sigma^2_k)
\end{equation}
However, this seems non-identifiable to me. If we don't restrict $\epsilon_k$, then the values of $X_k\beta_k$ and $\epsilon_k$ can exchange, and the likelihood would be equivalent. There seems to be no way to disentangle the effect of the two sets of covariates.

It seems to me that if I restrict $\beta_k$ to be the same across all subjects I have some chance, ie:
\begin{equation}
    y_k = X_k\beta + \epsilon_k
\end{equation}
since this induces some shrinkage towards a global value, but I am unsure if this would be enough to allow me to infer these effects. Is there an alteration I can make, or an alternative approach that would make this tractable?

Comment: Within a frequentist mixed effects framework, one can have a model for the residuals in addition to the typical model for the means. The model for the residuals can have time-varying or person-level predictors. However, I am wondering if I am somehow misunderstanding what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Erik, could you perhaps link to an example in a paper or book?

Comment: Hmm, upon fitting this model in stan ($y_k \sim N(X_k\beta_k + z_k\psi_k, \sigma^2_k)$ there doesn't seem to be any issues and I can recover $\psi$ almost exactly. Perhaps I'm overthinking things!

Comment: These models are sometimes referred to as heterogenous variance models. See https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/ILD_Ch06_2017_MLMwithHeterogeneousVariance.html for a detailed explanation and examples and also https://m-clark.github.io/mixed-models-with-R/extensions.html#heterogeneous-variance for a shorter example. And https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.3102/1076998614546494?casa_token=m7YuJh1DFQcAAAAA:hTjVwsjmM5QA3bg4PlVEKG2O4kK2W6WRVjIFDNqIaw88x6RjTyS2WvSQ8XA0-taIl96_q3y2zA

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll have a read.

Comment: Sure thing. The paper by Leckie et al. uses a Bayesian MCMC approach, albeit with largely diffuse priors.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I've had a look. I think this differs from what I want to accomplish as it deals with modelling the variance of residuals as a function of level 1/level 2 covariates. What I want to do is to model the residual values themselves as a function of those covariates. I think I need to think carefully about the problem though. Thanks again for the links though, I'm quite sure I'll use those models another time.

Comment: Hi Erik, this approach actually seems to work really well for my use case. If you'd like to post a quick answer I'd be delighted to accept it, otherwise please accept my endless gratitude, and know that I owe you a beer :)

Comment: Thanks @alanocallaghan. Added a response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to model the residual variance as a function of various predictors in your regression model, including time-varying and time-invariant predictors. Examples of this approach and its implementation in `nlme` can be found [here](https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/ILD_Ch06_2017_MLMwithHeterogeneousVariance.html) and also [here](https://m-clark.github.io/mixed-models-with-R/extensions.html#heterogeneous-variance). A similar approach can be utilized in Bayesian setups as well, e.g., [this](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.3102/1076998614546494?casa_token=m7YuJh1DFQcAAAAA:hTjVwsjmM5QA3bg4PlVEKG2O4kK2W6WRVjIFDNqIaw88x6RjTyS2WvSQ8XA0-taIl96_q3y2zA) article by Leckie et al.

The residual variance is modeled as a log-linear function of the time-varying and time-invariant predictors. In a frequentist mixed effects modeling paradigm, the residual variance ($\sigma^2$) is estimated from the model, but in this approach, its log is modeled directly as a function of predictors:

log($\sigma^2$) = $\alpha_{0j}$ + $\alpha_{1j}X_{ij}$.

As noted in the Leckie et al paper, if $\alpha_{0j}$ + $\alpha_{1j}X_{ij}$ are both equal to 0, the residual variance is constant across occasions (level 1 units in multilevel modeling parlance), which is the typical assumption of linear regression models.